# Creating separate line entries for multi-value fields

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with a list of items. Essentially it's an export from an issue tracking tool. One of the columns of that table contains comma-separated values. I am looking for a way to create separate entries for the individual values of multi-value entries.

Example: *(this is a simplified example, the real case contains around a dozen columns)*

**Source data:**

```
ID | Title          |  Areas Affected  |  
1  | Issue title A  |  Area X, Area Y  |  
2  | Issue title B  |  Area Y, Area Z  |  
3  | Issue title C  |  Area X, Area Z  |
```

**What I am trying to get to:**

```
ID | Title          |  Areas Affected  |   
1  | Issue title A  |  Area X          |  
1  | Issue title A  |  Area Y          |  
2  | Issue title B  |  Area Y          |  
2  | Issue title B  |  Area Z          |  
3  | Issue title C  |  Area X          |  
3  | Issue title C  |  Area Z          |
```

It is OK that there are now duplicate entries for IDs and Titles?

Is there a formula, macro, or VBA script to achieve this?

Comment: You will need to use VBA for that task. I don't see any way using plain simple Excel functions for this.

Comment: do you have more columns next to "Affected Areas" ?

Comment: @BrOSs Yep, that was a simplified example, the real case has more columns, around 8-10.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur VBA is also acceptable as a solution! Will update the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar at all with VBA ? If yes then try to think about the algorithm that needs to be used to solve this task. Basically it's simple. You need to split rows on that column using the comma as a separator. In VBA you have the Split() function that you can use to return an array. For the first element just put it back in the cell where the list was. For the others, insert a new line for each element in the array (meaning you can have n elements in that comma-separated list), copy the entire row on that new line and put the i-th value in there. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: @Levasseur I think that answered the question, maybe make it an answer instead of a comment? If it didn't answer the question then the OP is looking for a freelance programmer which is not what this forum is about.

Comment: @K_B OK, got the point! Seeking for a solution without doing some trial-n-error isn't in the spirit of SO I suppose :) I am not very familiar with VBA, but doing some reading and learning the basics shouldn't take long. I guess I will need to post a separate question once I have a non-working draft, at which point the community can comment on how to make it work, correct? :P

Comment: Correct ! VBA syntax is easy to learn if you have prior programming experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split rows on that column using the comma as a separator. In VBA you have the Split() function that you can use to return an array. For the first element just put it back in the cell where the list was. For the others, insert a new line for each element in the array (meaning you can have n elements in that comma-separated list), copy the entire row on that new line and put the i-th value in there.

Comment: I am not familiar with VBA, but thanks for leading me in the right direction, your answer satisfies the question. Will post another Q. once I have a draft VBA script (or maybe not if I make it work!)

Comment: @ulmas: please give the answer a tick for having answered your question (left of the message a V shaped, greyed out tick will be visible for you to click on), then we all know this one is answered. And welcome to the community

Comment: @K_B Yeah, I was kinda waiting if someone shows up and opts to do *free* freelancing by posting a script for me. Seems like it won't happen :) And thanks for welcoming me!

Answer (score 1):

After some reading/going through sample code, here's the answer if anyone needs. This is the actual working code, which doesn't fit 1:1 the examples I posted in the question.

```
Sub DataLobs()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Nice to have to increase the script speed. 

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    Dim curRowSrc As Integer
    Dim curRowDst As Integer
    Dim ttlRows As Integer
    Dim splitLob() As String

    ' Setting initial values to start rows in source and destination
    ' tables, as well as the total number of rows
    curRowSrc = 5
    curRowDst = 5
    ttlRows = 10000

    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Source") 'whatever you worksheet is
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Destination") 'or whatever your worksheet is called

    wsDst.Range("A5:F" & ttlRows).Clear

    ' Goes through column D in the source table
    ' and copies rows where the D cell is not blank
    ' into the destination table
    For curRowSrc = 5 To ttlRows
        If wsSrc.Range("D" & curRowSrc).Value <> "" Then ' There are some blank cells in the source table, so we are eliminating them.

            ' Split the cell value against the comma
            splitLob = Split(wsSrc.Range("D" & curRowSrc).Value, ", ") 'THIS IS WHERE @AlexandreP.Levasseur's HINT COMES INTO PLAY!

            For i = LBound(splitLob) To UBound(splitLob)
                wsDst.Range("A" & curRowDst).Value = splitLob(i)
                wsDst.Range("B" & curRowDst).Value = wsSrc.Range("A" & curRowSrc)
                wsDst.Range("C" & curRowDst).Value = wsSrc.Range("C" & curRowSrc)
                wsDst.Range("D" & curRowDst).Value = wsSrc.Range("AC" & curRowSrc)
                wsDst.Range("E" & curRowDst).Value = wsSrc.Range("AE" & curRowSrc)
                wsDst.Range("F" & curRowDst).Value = wsSrc.Range("AD" & curRowSrc)
                curRowDst = curRowDst + 1
            Next
        End If
    Next curRowSrc
End Sub
```